# Using a custom ListView in a ListFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-listfragment

I'm trying to implement [this dynamicListView](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BZIvjMgH-Q) from DevBytes inside a ListFragment.

source: http://developer.android.com/shareables/devbytes/ListViewDraggingAnimation.zip

I'm doing this by creating a simple layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.example.android.listviewdragginganimation.DynamicListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and inflating this layout in my ListFragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_list_layout, container);
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

The DynamicListView seems to have initialized correctly (it's init(Context) function is run). But it's just working as if it was just a normal ListView. i.e. items are all displayed and I can scroll up and down, but the DynamicListViews onItemLongClickListener never gets called.

Is there anything else that needs to be done to use a custom ListView in a ListFragment?

Comment: u need to override `onItemLongClickListener` in your `fragment`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inflating your custom layout but returning the default one. Change your code to

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_list_layout, container);
}
```

After that you can call `getListView().setOnLongClickListener(myClickListener)` as normal.

Edit: Add a second view inside your layout with the id `android:id="@id/android:empty"` for a bonus empty-state.